# Changing .Net Configuration Settings during installation

Tags: c#, installation, configurationmanager

I have to create a Installer Class which will change the ConnectionString Settings of all config files in a application through Windows Installer Setup in Visual Studio (Custom Dialog boxes).

Comment: @Justin, be careful on your spelling when editing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although not an installer based solution, you could look at [ConfigGen](http://configgen.codeplex.com) **[Disclosure**: I am the author of ConfigGen **]**.

This allows you, amongst other things, to "tokenise" your config file so that some settings (such as your connection string) are filled in at config generation time (which can be build time, deploy time, etc) based on the settings that have been specified in a spreadsheet. This gives you a simple, tabulated view of all the different settings across environments and machines.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not providing an example, but you can use an [Installer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx). That's basically what they're for.